# get decimal input in django_filters.FilterSet

Tags: django, django-filter

how will filter decimal value using django-filter. I need to input decimal value using the filter form.

```
height_lesser = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='height',lookup_expr='lte', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

I need to change the widget to DecimalInput but it is not supported. In the model i have used DecimalField.

Comment: Have you tried like this `attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'step' = 0.1}`

Comment: No haven't tried that. But i cannot input a decimal on the filter.form in template ( Validation error- display a valid input)

Comment: when you are trying to give a decimal value as input in that form it throws error ?

Comment: No i cannot run the code because there is no decimal input ( if i give NumberInput widget and try to give decimal number - it shows validation error

Comment: have you checked by giving `step` in `attrs` like above I mentioned

Comment: Will try that. Thanks

Comment: Working successfully. Thanks for the help

Comment: So what code you are added ? the above one ?

Comment: added step: 0.1 in attrs as you have told

Comment: So I'am adding it on answers. That may help others facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add step in attrs like this :

```
attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'step' = 0.1}
```